# How to remove a word say "code" from myArray[1] and NOT the full myArray[1] using C#

Tags: c#

How to remove a word say "code" from myArray[1] and NOT the full myArray[1].

```
string[] myArray = new string[3];
            myArray[0] = "Hello World";
            myArray[1] = "This is a sample code";
            myArray[2] = "Delete me";
```

Comment: Break the question down into smaller parts. First, you'll need to get the current string from the array element. Then, you'll need to modify the string. Finally, you can re-assign the new string to the array element. Each of these steps is documented countless times on the Internet and Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Replace(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: What solutions have you tried to implement? What hasn't worked with them?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you saying you want to look inside a string array, searching for text to remove. If `myArray[i]` does not contain the search text, leave it alone. If it does contain the search text, then change `myArray[i]` so it refers to a string like the previous version, but with the search text removed? If so, my question is basically the algorithm you want

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Replace` method

```
myArray[1] = myArray[1].Replace("code", "");
```

More about `Replace` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.Replace()` to substitute the target word with an empty string:

```cs
string[] myArray = new string[3];
myArray[0] = "Hello World";
myArray[1] = "This is a sample code";
myArray[2] = "Delete me";

foreach(var s in myArray) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

Console.WriteLine("=================");

// One specific entry

myArray[1] = myArray[1].Replace("code", "");

foreach(var s in myArray) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

Console.WriteLine("=================");

// All entries (if there were multiple)

for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = myArray[i].Replace("code", "");
}       

foreach(var s in myArray) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

```
Hello World
This is a sample code
Delete me
=================
Hello World
This is a sample 
Delete me
=================
Hello World
This is a sample 
Delete me
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/N0LkKI

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this, some of which are already mentioned. Here's an alternative solution using an extension routine.

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void ReplaceText(this string[] array, string word, int index = 0, string newWord = "", bool replaceAll = false)
        {
            if (array?.Length > 0 && word != null)
            {
                if (replaceAll)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        // You could check if it contains the 
                        // word before trying to replace it
                        array[i] = array[i].Replace(word, newWord);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (array.Length >= index)
                        array[index] = array[index].Replace(word, newWord);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example Usage:

```
  myArray.ReplaceText("code", 1); //replace just the word at that index
  myArray.ReplaceText("code", replaceAll: true); //replace the word in all index's
```

Also worth noting, look into using [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) if you can, they are much easier to work with and manage than arrays.

Comment: It also worked but only I used the array[i].replace(). thanks for the help.